# How to set Base URL in Axios, based on a user input - React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, axios

I am building an app where the user connects to a server by entering the URL when logging in.

Each server provides an API and I can't hard-code the value for the BaseURL when creating the Axios client instance. I somehow need to globally store the URL and set it based on the user input in the login form.

So I would like to know what is a proper way to do this. I am really not sure what is the best approach to dynamically store a value that I can access when creating the API connection. Any ideas and best practice suggestions are welcome.

Here is the code for creating the API connection: client.js

```js
import { create } from 'apisauce';

const api = create({
    baseURL: "BASE_URL_FROM_USER_INPUT" + "server/odata/"
});

export default api;
```

This is how I use the API: users.js

```js
import api from './client';

const getUsers = () => api.get("/users");

export default {
    getUsers
}
```

This is how I will get my data:

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import usersApi from '../api/users';

const TestScreenAuthenticated = ({navigation}) => {
    const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        loadUsers();
    });

    const loadUsers = async () => {
        const response = await usersApi.getUsers();
        setUsers(response);
    }

    ...
};

export default TestScreenAuthenticated;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the `localStore`to store the baseUrl.

```
//save the value
localStore.setItem('baseUrl', value)

//read the value
localStore.getItem('baseUrl')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can use the .env file in your project and put the web service address there. This file is out of reach of the user viewing the site and will not be able to edit it

this link:
https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/